# Nested comments in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, comments

Is it possible to enable nested comments (/* /* */ */) in Visual C++?

I can't seem to find the switch, if there is one.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nested comments are not allowed in the C++ standard.  Visual C++ supports this standard.

Sorry, no nested comments.

Comment: Thanks. I was sure I was once able to do this, but maybe I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's possible using that style of quote.  The first "*/" will always "close" the quote.

Comment: Note: This is true of C++ (the language), not just Visual C++ (the implementation).

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that is possible, but if you want to "comment out" a chunk of code which itself contains comments, you could always use the preprocessor,

```
#ifdef NOT_REQUIRED

/**
 * foo
 */
 void foo()
 { 

 }

#endif
```

Comment: I frequently use "#if 0" - the code can easily be re-enabled by changing the 0 to a 1.