# Nested Comments in C++

Tags: c++, comments

This should be a common problem and possibly similar to some question here but i am looking foe the best way to comment out multiple lines (rather methods ) in C++ which have comments within them .I did check out some posts on SO but couldnt get the *full* details on using something like if #0 .

I did check out this post [Nested comments in Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939753/nested-comments-in-visual-c) but I am not on the Windows platform.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are almost correct; essentially it is being suggested to "if-def" the section of code out.  What you want to do is use the precompiler directive `#if` to block the code for you.  Ex below shows that I want to ignore everything between the if and endif.

```
#if 0
/* Giant comment
 it doesn't matter what I put here */

// it will be ignored forever.
#endif
```

To answer your question in general though; there is not a way to have compound comments, i.e.

```
/* 
  /* */ <--- this closes the first /* 
*/ <--- this dangles.
```

Answer (score 3):

The stuff between the `#if 0` and `#endif` will be ignored by the compiler. (Your preprocessor might actually strip it out before the "compiler" can even take a look at it!)

```
#if 0

    /* 42 is the answer. */

    Have you tried jQuery?

    @Compiler Stop ignoring me!!

#endif
```

---

You'll have better control if you use `#ifdef`s:

```
// #define DEBUG


#ifdef DEBUG
   MyFunction();
   std::cout << "DEBUG is defined!";
#endif


// Later in your code...

#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "DEBUG is still defined!";
#endif
```

Just uncomment the first line, and your `#ifdef DEBUG` code will suddenly be visible to the compiler.

---

P.S. This should clear any more confusion:

```
/*
    cout << "a";
    /*
        cout << "b";
    */
    cout << "c";
*/
```

The output should be `"c"`, assuming your compiler doesn't give you any errors for the last `*/`.

Comment: Another useful thing to note is that you can define DEBUG at compile time with the -D switch in gcc/g++ (and any respectable compiler). For example, if you want to compile your debug build, you would do `gcc main.c -DDEBUG` and DEBUG would be defined for that compilation. This is much more versatile than statically defining DEBUG within a file.

Answer (score 3):

Use whatever means your editor provides to add `//` a the beginning of all lines.

For example in Vim you can mark the lines as a visual block and then insert at the beginning of all lines with `I//`. In Visual Studio you can use the `CTRL-K-C` shortcut to comment code blocks.

Comment: So that's why Vim does that.

Answer (score 1):

Another route assuming you are using Visual Studio is there is a handy keyboard shortcut to comment all of the currently selected code, adding `//` before each line. `CTRL+K`+`CTRL+C` to comment and `CTRL+K`+`CTRL+U` to uncomment.